# Android Single Sign On

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hi friends i am implementing FaceBook with Single Sign On and downloaded code from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.. I registeres apps in Facebook and generated Hash key but Still SINGLE SIGN ON not working..Any important thing i wanna to do.... I dont knw where i want to add the Authorize code.. Whether i want add authurize code in FACEBOOK.java or in  my mAIN activity APP.java extends Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the call to authorizeCallback() in your activity code ? You need to put it in the onActivityResult method of your activity.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  // ... anything else your app does onActivityResult ...
}
```